# I need some clarification about whether I should (could?) deallocate view-related UI elements or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, view

So I do understand, that I should release the objects that I own. (`alloc/copy/retain` stuff)

And I also do understand(kinda?), that if I had `@property` with `retain` in some of my class, or some instance variable with alloc/init, then I should write a custom dealloc to make sure those ones gets deallocated with that class.

What I do not understand is should I manually release the `cell` objects for example? (since I am creating it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with alloc/init? Yea, I know, that tableView should kill those cells when it gets deallocated, but do I want to make sure?

Also, could I manually release `UILabel`, `UITextField` and so on? I do know that those are gets killed when you deallocate the view, but again, still, do I want to make sure?

UPDATE:
Yea, thanks for the tip about reference counting, but the project exact purpose is to do some simple stuff, using manual memory management.
It is funny how most of the tutors nowadays skips this part entirely so the novice like myself have to figure all that stuff by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a `strong`/`retain` pointer to a UI element they will be automatically dealloced once they go out of the screen.

Regarding the `cell`s - you should never `dealloc` them because they're intended to be reused. If you `dealloc` and re-`init` them you'll get a **REALLY** bad performance while scrolling.

Also, as [Glorfindel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31488941/2177402) said, consider using [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) (if you're not using already) and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C supports [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) which does almost all memory management for you. I suggest you migrate your old code to ARC; this is quite easy (Xcode has refactoring support for this) and it will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but enabling arc goes contrary to the task